# I have a question about combination series. i don't understand that

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, gamma-function, binomial-theorem, beta-function

$$
\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{n+r+1} {n \choose r} 
= \frac{
\sqrt{\pi}~ 2^{-2n-1} n !
}{
\left(n  + \frac{1}{2} \right)!
}
$$

How to explain what is the left series become to right form? I calculated by wolfram and received it but I couldn't that how to transform from a combination formula in the left series to the useful tool(ex: factorial or double). so I don't know about concrete solution.
(sorry, I'm not good at English because I was born in korea. If you don't like this terrible sentence, Please forgive me...)

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{n+r+1}=\int_{0}^{1} x^{n+r} dx$

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the LHS introduce

$$f(z)  = (-1)^n n! \frac{1}{z+n+1} \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

This has the property that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=r} f(z)
= (-1)^n n! \frac{1}{r+n+1}
\prod_{q=0}^{r-1} \frac{1}{r-q}
\prod_{q=r+1}^n \frac{1}{r-q}
\\ = (-1)^n n! \frac{1}{r+n+1}
\frac{1}{r!}
\frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{(n-r)!}
= \frac{1}{r+n+1}
(-1)^r {n\choose r}.$$

As we seek to compute

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{r+n+1}
(-1)^r {n\choose r}$$

and residues sum to zero with the residue at infinity being zero by
inspection we get for our sum

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=-n-1} f(z)
= - (-1)^n n! \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{-n-1-q}
= n! \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{n+1+q}
\\ = \frac{n!\times n!}{(2n+1)!}.$$

On the other hand working with the RHS we have with the Legendre
duplication formula

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi} 2^{-2n-1} n!}{(n+1/2)!}
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} 2^{-2n-1} n!}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}
\\ = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} 2^{-2n-1} \times n! \times n!}
{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(n+3/2)}
\\ = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} 2^{-2n-1} \times n! \times n!}
{2^{1-2(n+1)} \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(2n+2)}
= \frac{n!\times n!}{(2n+1)!}.$$

We see that the LHS and the RHS are identical as claimed.

Comment: Elegant and instructive derivation. (+1)

Comment: Thanks! Is the new user name close to some famous constant when evaluated properly?

Comment: My pleasure and yes, good observation. :-) I like the story connected with this famous constant and I admire the number theoretic magic of $163$. The reason for this change was due the recent layout update, which too often shows icon and name  violationg my privacy expectations.

Comment: May I point to this *[nice binomial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275873)*. It looks utterly harmless, but I wasn't able to find a solution up to now. Maybe it's also interesting for you to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

> We obtain following the hint of @ZAhmed:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n}&\color{blue}{ \frac{(-1)^r}{n+r+1} \binom{n}{r}}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\int_{0}^1 z^{n+r}\,dz\binom{n}{r}\tag{1}\\
> &=\int_{0}^1z^n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}(-z)^r\,dz\\
> &=\int_{0}^1z^n(1-z)^n\,dz\tag{2}\\
> &=B(n+1,n+1)\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n+1)}{2^{2n+1}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,n!}{2^{2n+1}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)!}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $\frac{1}{q+1}=\int_0^1{z^q}\,dz$
- In (2) we apply the binomial theorem.
- in (3) we observe we have the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*.
- In (4) we represent the beta funtion with *[Gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties)*.
- In (5) we recall the *[Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula)*
  \begin{align*}
  \Gamma(z)\Gamma\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(2z)
  \end{align*}
  evaluated at $z=n+1$.
- In (6) we use the identity $\Gamma(z+1)=z!$.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I may look at it. The reason I did not as yet is that it has two close votes already, indicating a trend toward ultimate closure.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I see. Thanks for your interest in this problem. The near symmetry and the right-hand side might indicate a telescoping approach. If this problem will be closed, I think I'll open a new question based upon it.