# Proving $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{(k-2){n-k+2\choose k-1}+k{n-k+1\choose k-1}}{k{n\choose k}}=1$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

My friend showed me a difficult combinatorial identity I cannot solve.

> Prove that:
> $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{(k-2){n-k+2\choose k-1}+k{n-k+1\choose k-1}}{k{n\choose k}}=1$$ for all $n\ge 2$.

How do I prove this?

Edit: I would like to bump this again, due to lack of attention.

Comment: Induction seems like a big clue... and there is an identity for $k \times \binom{n}{k}$...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Are you saying that you know how to prove it, or are you speculating?

Comment: Speculating, I may try it later in the day.

Comment: Well we could rewrite $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$, but I do not know if it helps much. I'm also not sure how induction will work, as sum for $n$ have all different denominators from the sum for $n-1$.

Comment: It does, check that doing what Sean proposes, your identity is equivalent to show that $\sum _{k=2}^n\binom{n-k+1}{k-2}(k-1)!(n-k)!(2n-3k+4)=n!$ You can try induction in that one(I did not see any combinatorial proof rightaway).

Comment: Maybe you can recognize the summand as a probability, as in this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3323822/683666

Comment: For what its worth, Mathematica is able to simplify the expression above to $1+\frac{1}{n^2\Gamma[2-n]\Gamma[n]}$ which only requires a little bit of work to finish. Of course, its anyone's guess how it does this. Also, if you allow $n$ to be continuous (with upper bounds as $\lceil n\rceil$ then there is a hidden $2$-periodicity in the sum. I'm not sure if this is useful, but induction might prove easier if one goes from $n\to n+2$ and have two separate base cases.

Comment: @jxia1234: Non-substantive edits *just* to bump a question are inappropriate. Rather, you should make substantive edits to improve the quality of the question. (For instance, you can add a more-informative title, as I just did for you. :)  You can also [offer a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) to call attention to a question.

Answer (score 3):

I do not like this proof, for reasons that will become obvious.

By shifting the summation index and using a binomial ID in the denominator, we can write the LHS (left-hand side) of the proposed identity as
$$D_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{ (k-1)\binom{n-k+1}{k} + (k+1)\binom{n-k}{k} }{n\binom{n-1}{k}} $$
For the denominator, use the ID (beta integral identity)
$$\frac{1}{n\binom{n-1}{k}}=\int_0^1t^k(1-t)^{n-1-k} dt = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}
\cos^{2k+1}(t) \ \sin^{2n-2k-1}(t) dt $$
This is done so that the sum can be solved in explicit form in terms of the Chebyshev polynomials of first and second kind. e.g.,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kx^{2k}\binom{n-k}{k} = U_n\big(\frac{1}{2x}\big)x^n$$
With one integration by parts and simplification, we can write an equivalent expression, with $\omega_n(t)=(n\cos^{2n-1}(t)-(n+1)\cos^{2n+1}(t))\sin{(t)},$

$$ (eq.1) \quad \frac{1}{2}D_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \omega_n(t)(i\tan{t})^{n+1}U_{n+1}\big(\frac{1}{2i\ \tan{t}} \big) dt \quad+  $$
$$+ \quad \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \omega_n(t)(i\tan{t})^{n}U_{n}\big(\frac{1}{2i\ \tan{t}} \big) dt 
-\frac{2}{n+1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \omega_n(t)(i\tan{t})^{n+1}T_{n+1}\big(\frac{1}{2i\ \tan{t}} \big) dt$$

At this point I tried to use recurrence formulas for the Chebyshev polynomials to prove $D_{n+1} = D_n,$ but I was unsuccessful.  Therefore, I did the following:  create a generating function by operating on both sides with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n $.  Now by explicit calculation, $D_1 = 0.$  Therefore we want to verify
$$ (eq.2)\quad -(x+\log{(1-x)})/2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n \ RHS(*) $$
To do this, you need six explicit sums, which are not difficult to derive:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} U_{n}(y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \text{arctan}\big(x\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1-xy}\big)-\frac{1}{2}\log{(1+x^2-2xy)} $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} U_{n+1}(y) = \frac{2y^2-1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \text{arctan}\big(x\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1-xy}\big)-y\log{(1+x^2-2xy)} $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n U_{n}(y) = \frac{1}{1-2xy+x^2}-1 $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n U_{n+1}(y) =\frac{1}{x}\Big( \frac{1}{1-2xy+x^2}-1 -2xy\Big)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1} T_{n+1}(y) = \frac{1}{x}\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\log{(1+x^2-2xy)} - xy\Big) $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} T_{n+1}(y) = -\sqrt{1-y^2} \text{arctan}\big(x\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1-xy}\big)-\frac{y}{2}\log{(1+x^2-2xy)} $$

With these closed forms, the indefinite integrals are solvable in closed form by Mathematica.  There is *considerable* simplification needed to finally get the form on the LHS of (eq.2).

I *detest* this proof because it does not give a hint at all about how the identity was discovered, and the huge amounts of simplification that must be performed with a CAS and human intervention.

Answer (score 3):

This can be turned into a telescoping sum.

Applying the Pascal's triangle recurrence to the first binomial coefficient in the numerator yields
$$
\binom{n-k+2}{k-1}=\binom{n-k+1}{k-2}+\binom{n-k+1}{k-1},
$$
which allows us to rewrite the identity as
$$
D_n=\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{(k-2)\binom{n-k+1}{k-2}+2(k-1)\binom{n-k+1}{k-1}}{k\binom{n}{k}}=1.\tag{1}
$$
We have named the left side of the identity $D_n$ and observed that the upper limit can be taken to be $\infty$ since the summand becomes $0$ after $k\approx\frac{n}{2}$.

The sum now telescopes by combining the second term of the $k^\text{th}$ summand with the first term of the $(k+1)^\text{st}$ summand:
\begin{align}
D_n&=\frac{(2-2)\binom{n-2+1}{2-2}}{2\binom{n}{2}}+\sum_{k\ge2}\left[\frac{2(k-1)\binom{n-k+1}{k-1}}{k\binom{n}{k}}+\frac{(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge2}\left[\frac{2(k-1)(n-k)\binom{n-k+1}{k-1}}{kn\binom{n-1}{k}}+\frac{(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{n\binom{n-1}{k}}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge2}\left[\frac{2(k-1)(n-k)\left[\binom{n-k}{k-2}+\binom{n-k}{k-1}\right]}{kn\binom{n-1}{k}}+\frac{(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{n\binom{n-1}{k}}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge2}\left[\frac{(k-2)n\binom{n-k}{k-2}+k(n-2k+2)\binom{n-k}{k-2}+2(k-1)(n-k)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{kn\binom{n-1}{k}}+\frac{(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{n\binom{n-1}{k}}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{(k-2)n\binom{n-k}{k-2}+k(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}+2n(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}-2k(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}+k(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{kn\binom{n-1}{k}}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{(k-2)\binom{n-k}{k-2}+2(k-1)\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{k\binom{n-1}{k}}\\
&=D_{n-1}.
\end{align}
In the second line we have used $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n}{n-r}\binom{n-1}{r}$ to rewrite the first denominator and $r\binom{n}{r}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ to rewrite the second denominator. In the third line we have used the Pascal's triangle recurrence in the first numerator. Since $D_n=D_{n-1}$, the result follows by induction.

The denominator of the summand of $(1)$ is the number of selections of $k$ elements from $n$ with one marked element. Let's say that the $n$ elements are members of an organization ranked by seniority, with $1$ having highest seniority and $n$ having lowest, and that a committee of $k$ members is to be chosen with one member designated as chairperson. Then the numerator of the summand may be interpreted as the number of such committees in which the highest seniority member has rank $k-2$ or $k-1$ and in which the chairperson has seniority lower than either of those members. It might be interesting to try to understand the manipulations above in terms of this interpretation.

Comment: @WillOrrick: Congratulation to your great solution! It's as instructive as impressive. (+1)